# Как из дробного числа вернуть время?

Tags: javascript

Например расстояние - s = 1666, известна скорость - v = 60км.ч.

чтобы узнать время нужно:

```
const s = 1666;
const v = 60
const t = s / v; //27.7666666667
```

Как t  - вернуть в формате часы минуты секунды?

Comment: Часы/Минуты/Секунды относительно чего? Если относительно 1970, то `Date(t*60*60*1000)`

Comment: Нужно просто вернуть строку  например "0 18 25"

Answer (score -1):

```
const hours = Math.floor(t / 3600);
const minutes = Math.floor((t - hours * 3600) / 60);
const seconds = Math.floor(t - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60);

const formattedTime = ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds};
console.log(formattedTime); // 0:27:46
```

Попробуйте так. Непонятно в каких единицах s, но, если имелось ввиду 27,76 минут, а не часов, то должно сработать.